# Is there a way to invoke a delay to test a system that requires a long time to process a transaction?

Tags: maven, junit

We are using JUnit (and Maven) to test the proper insertion of documents into a MarkLogic server.  The files being ingested are very large and go through a complicated and time-consuming process as they are ingested, often taking tens of seconds or a couple of minutes to complete.

Is there a good clean way to periodically poll for the results we are looking for in the system?  If we could poll every ten seconds that would meet our needs.  I have seen people say to use Thread.sleep() in Java but this does not feel like a proper solution.  I have RTFM'd this in JUnit and am not finding a solution.  Perhaps Maven can be involved in the solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your tests, you can try the [Awaitility framework](http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/).

You can set a timeout, and also a callback that checks for the completion of the long task (if the task is asynchronous).

Answer (score 0):

I use the loop and Thread.sleep for the rare instances I need to do this.  (It is usually for queues though so I'm not going to be waiting for more than 20 seconds.)  Try every X seconds and then after Y seconds give up and fail. Nico's solution of awaitility sounds better though.

Maven wouldn't help with this problem. Maven is a build serve.  The only way it could help is to use a "stub" library instead of the real web service for testing.  But that isn't what you want to test.